# How this function excatly works?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have seen this code.

```
def theDay(year,month,day):
days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
months = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
if month < 3:
    year = year-1
theDay = days[int((year + year //4 - year // 100 +year // 400 + months[month-1] +day)) %7]
return theDay
```

Can someone assist me how this function exactly works?

Answer (score 0):

It uses a mathematical equations which accounts for the date itself, the century and for leap years of course
For the exact explanation I would recommend for you to visit:
https://artofmemory.com/blog/how-to-calculate-the-day-of-the-week-4203.html

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.